# Rails link_to and f.submit parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Example,

I made a scaffold project like,

```
rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

and if i go to

```
localhost:3000/posts
```

It shows the view like this,

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Content</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
    <td><%= post.title %></td>
    <td><%= post.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

My question is about the link_to method second parameter.

If i see the html code, it translate the code like this in the a tag.

```
<a href="/posts/1">Show</a>
<a href="/posts/1/edit">Edit</a>
<a href="/posts/1" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
<a href="/posts/new">New Post</a>
```

How does it parse to HTML code?

I don't understand the second parameters, like post, edit_post_path, this kind of stuff.

Second Question.

When the user wants to make a new post, it goes to this view.

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and if i look at form tag, it shows like this.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts" class="new_post" id="new_post" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="5d3i4uFDrhq+qenAWLbBxWqaA6rJAKrPedVIO04NK6o="></div>

  <div class="field">
    <label for="post_name">Name</label><br>
    <input id="post_name" name="post[name]" size="30" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="post_title">Title</label><br>
    <input id="post_title" name="post[title]" size="30" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="post_content">Content</label><br>
    <textarea cols="40" id="post_content" name="post[content]" rows="20"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Post">
  </div>
</form>
```

My question is, where does the action attribute has been set?

and how does the params are sending to the controller?

In my study, this is calling posts_controller's create method.

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

If it is like this, if i want to call this method. Doesn't the action has to be posts/create?

Man....Rails is so hard for newbies, and the api doc is so inconvenient :(

Comment: If you have multiple questions, please post them separately, not in the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
```

Here, `post` is a resource, and Rails generates URL's for resources based on their type. If you call `link_to` and pass an `ActiveRecord` object as the second parameter, such as your `post` object, it will look up the `show` URL for your `Post` class.

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
```

Again, `edit_post_path` is a method that's auto generated by Rails when you put a `resources :posts` in your `routes.rb` file. When you call that method, it returns the URL for editing the `post` object.

The destroy link is a slightly different story. In Rails you cannot delete a resource with a GET link. When you tell `link_to` that you want to delete, it actually creates a hidden form on the page that submits a delete request (this is not a true DELETE request because you can't issue that from the browser; instead it's a POST with a `method=_delete` as a parameter), and when you click the rendered link, the framework JavaScript will submit that hidden form.

Type in `rake routes` to see all the routes that Rails has generated from what's in your `routes.rb` file, and as suggested, read up on Rails routing in general, as well as REST.

For your second question.

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
```

Again, this is a REST thing. Rails will ask if the object is a new record or not. If so, it knows to render the `form` tag with the `post` method pointed to the `index` action; otherwise, it will render the `form` tag with the `put` method pointed to the object's URL.

Answer (score 1):

Question: "I don't understand the second parameters, like post, edit_post_path, this kind of stuff."

Answer: `edit_post_path` is the route to edit your Post resource. It takes a reference to the current Post as an argument so that it will know which Post you wish to edit.

Ruby on Rails creates restful routes for all of your resources, so when you generate a scaffolding around your Post model, you get index, edit, show, and new routes automagically.

You might want to take a look at this [Rails routing tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) which should give you a better grasp of how routing works.

As for your other questions, you should really break them out into separate posts as Tamer pointed out to better suit the Q&A format of StackOverflow.